# When using the pack layout of Tkinter, how can I have a Label's wraplength be equal to the width of the window when it is resized?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I'm using the `pack` layout of `Tkinter`, and I allow the application window to be resized.

What I can't figure out is how to have the `wraplength` of a `ttk.Label` be variable based on window size? I'm open to any implementation that allows a `Label` in the `pack` layout to wrap based on window size, including if it somehow uses other attributes, such as `width`.

`ttk.Label(frame, text=text_1, wraplength=500, justify=LEFT, style='my.TLabel').pack(anchor='nw')`

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Have my Tkinter Label display nicely when the window is resized. Either I don't set a wraplength and it exceeds the width of the window, or I do and the Label does not respond at all to changes in Window size.

Comment: That suggests another problem, what you're trying to do is solving it upside down. I'd rather see the images of bad and good. There has to be a simpler solution.

Comment: @Nae can you explain further? To me it's acting as coded. Where do you see the potential for another problem?

Comment: I mean it _sounds_ like you're trying to solve an easy problem with a hard answer. I feel like you're asking, "How can enlarge my bucket under this faucet?" where you can simply cut-off the water using the faucet. I can't say for sure as for the lack of [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put a binding on the `<Configure>` event for the label. When the label resizes, the event will fire and you can reset the wraplength to be the new width of the widget.

Here's a simple contrived example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief="groove")
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

        label = ttk.Label(frame, width=30, background="bisque",
                          borderwidth=1, relief="sunken", padding=4,
                          text=("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur " 
                                "adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor "
                                "incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"))
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=10, pady=10)

        label.bind("<Configure>", self.set_label_wrap)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def set_label_wrap(self, event):
        wraplength = event.width-12 # 12, to account for padding and borderwidth
        event.widget.configure(wraplength=wraplength)

Example().start()
```